# Convert data in Laravel 5.8 dive wrong result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel.
I use in my project Laravel 5.8.
I have this code:

```
$dataTimeFromDb = '2019-12-28T23:54:04.000000Z';
$userLastActivity = Carbon::parse($dataTimeFromDb)->format('Y-m-d H:m');
```

In result I have: 2019-12-29 00:12.

I need value from DB in format: Y-m-d H:m. My timezone is Warsaw/Berlin and I save in this format in DB.

How can I repeir it?

Comment: You want to convert this 2019-12-28T23:54:04.000000Z to  2019-12-29 00:12??

Comment: In what format you store date in db?

Comment: In db i have: 2019-12-29 00:54:04  (data format in db: datetime)

Comment: @traffka something goes wrong when you retrieve it from db

Comment: @traffka How do you define date column in your model class?

Comment: I have datetime. I haven't definition in model. This is my model: https://pastebin.com/x1Zvb9CH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `format` only can do the trick. Try it and let me know.

```
$dataTimeFromDb->format('Y-m-d H:i')
```